# Reason for assigning RewriteBase to an environment variable

Tags: apache, symfony, mod-rewrite

I am working on an existing Symfony project, which uses the following Apache rewrite rule which I think originally came from Symfony itself (you can see an example of it here: https://gist.github.com/deehidayat/050eb02100be57c03f22):

```
# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

As far as I can see, the end result of this is that if `RewriteBase` has been set, the value of this is extracted and assigned to the `BASE` environment variable, and if not, `BASE` remains unset - so far so good!

Later on, the environment variable is used like this:

```
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

i.e. redirect everything to the front controller, relative to the `RewriteBase` as appropriate.

I'm pretty new to `mod_rewrite`, so have been struggling to work this out, but this part confuses me because I thought that `RewriteRule` was supposed to automatically prepend `RewriteBase` to the target URL anyway?

**Why do we need to use an environment variable here, and shouldn't this result in the `RewriteBase` being prepended twice?**

I hope the question makes sense - I'm probably missing something fairly basic!

Comment: Try this settings https://gist.github.com/tulik/31c20e23ae2693f1b79c52a684831da8

Comment: Did you even read my question?